# How can I convert query from a URL in Vue.js to string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have `this.$route.query` in which the object is:

```
{ next: "/api/o/authorize/?client_id=xxx", nonce: "bee", redirect_uri: "http://X.app.net/oauth/providers/appZ/callback", response_type: "code", scope: "read", state: "123" }
```

How to convert it to:

```
/api/o/authorize/?client_id=xxx&nonce=bee&redirect_uri=http://X.app.net/oauth/providers/appZ/callback&response_type=code&scope=read&state=123
```

Maybe I missed something and there is a method for this in Vue or Js?

Comment: That's it's in `query` means that the whole thing is a query, `?next=/api/o/authorize...&nonce=bee&...`. Notice that a path in `next` needs to be URL encoded. Consider explaining your case. It's unclear why you expect `next` to become a path.

Comment: You'll probably have to build the URL yourself. Check out [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). They should handle all the URL encoding so you don't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe plain, single-level objects through `URLSearchParams` to form correctly encoded query strings.

For example

```js
// just an example to match your Vue code
this.$route = {
  query: { next: "/api/o/authorize/?client_id=xxx", nonce: "bee", redirect_uri: "http://X.app.net/oauth/providers/appZ/callback", response_type: "code", scope: "read", state: "123" }
}

const { next, ...params } = this.$route.query
const url = `${next}&${new URLSearchParams(params)}`

console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a computed property called `query` :

```
computed:{
  query(){
    let q=this.$route.query;
      return Object.keys(q).map(k=>`${k}=${q[k]}`).join('&').replace("next=","")
  }
}
```

example in js :

```js
let q={ next: "/api/o/authorize/?client_id=xxx", nonce: "bee", redirect_uri: "http://X.app.net/oauth/providers/appZ/callback", response_type: "code", scope: "read", state: "123" }

let query=Object.keys(q).map(k=>`${k}=${q[k]}`).join('&').replace("next=","")

console.log(query)
```